# Why is required="true" not triggered when rendered="false"

Tags: validation, jsf, required, rendered-attribute

I have a some doubts about parsing of html tags in facelet. Let we have facelet which contains the follow

```
<h:inputText id="username"
             title="My name is: "
             value="#{hello.name}"
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="Error: A name is required."
             rendered="false"
             maxlength="25" />
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response">
            </h:commandButton>
```

After submit click i haven't `Error: A name is required`. Why? `username` just not rendered, and after `submit` click there is no value in `username`.

Comment: Which JSF version and impl are you using?

Comment: @Luiggi: behavior is as per JSF spec, thus unlikely an impl/version specific problem.

Comment: @BalusC I misread the *I haven't* by *I have*, thus finding this behavior really odd.

Comment: @Luiggi: ah, I can definitely imagine that, I also had to read the question twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rendered` attribute is also evaluated during validations and update model values phases. For evidence, check [`javax.faces.component.UIInput` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) (line numbers are as per  Mojarra 2.2.0):

```
696     public void processValidators(FacesContext context) {
697 
698         if (context == null) {
699             throw new NullPointerException();
700         }
701 
702         // Skip processing if our rendered flag is false
703         if (!isRendered()) {
704             return;
705         }
...
...
...
735     public void processUpdates(FacesContext context) {
736 
737         if (context == null) {
738             throw new NullPointerException();
739         }
740 
741         // Skip processing if our rendered flag is false
742         if (!isRendered()) {
743             return;
744         }
```

The explanation is simple: this is a safeguard against tampered (spoofed/hacked) HTTP requests wherein endusers purposefully manipulate the HTTP request in an attempt to set values and/or invoke actions of hidden inputs/commands which they are most likely simply not allowed to update or invoke, such as a delete button which shows only when the user has admin role:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" ... rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}" />
```

Note: component's `readonly` and `disabled` attributes are also treated this way. For your particular purpose, use CSS `display: none` instead.

```
<h:inputText ... style="display:none" />
```

*(note: this is a kickoff example, using `style` attribute is bad practice in HTML/CSS perspective, prefer `styleClass` with a concrete CSS file)*

Although I wonder the concrete functional requirement behind this, this is bad for UX. Perhaps you were just randomly experimenting around without first studying the [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html) let alone [JSF source code](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)?